# java.io.FileNotFoundException - file DOES exist in directory

Tags: java, file, filenotfoundexception, fileinputstream

I keep receiving the same error whilst trying to read a file. The file DOES exist in the directory, what am I doing wrong?

```
package test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MenuSample{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File f = new File("C:/Users/Joe/Documents/workspace/ArtificialLifeFX/res/latest.txt");

        Scanner scanner = null;
        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(f);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        scanner.useDelimiter("\r\n");
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Joe\Documents\workspace\ArtificialLifeFX\res\latest.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at test.MenuSample.main(MenuSample.java:16)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at test.MenuSample.main(MenuSample.java:21)
```

Forgive me if I'm being naive, I'm new to java. I'm running Eclipse Luna on Windows 7.

Comment: couple of thoughts...Java is case sensitive with file names whereas windows is not, so make sure the case matches.

Comment: Also, your delimiter in the string is forward slashes, and windows is backslashes. I'm not sure if Java is smart enought to account for this.

Comment: To test if the path really exists you can try opening a shell and type `cd C:\Users\Joe\Documents\workspace\ArtificialLifeFX\res\`

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to check the values of f.exists() and f.canRead() before creating the scanner.

Comment: have tried both uppercase and lowercase, and forward slashes and backslashes, no luck...

Comment: opening that folder in the shell works as it should, so it's definitely there

Comment: Try `notepad "C:/Users/Joe/Documents/workspace/ArtificialLifeFX/res/latest.txt"` in a shell. Does that open your file?

Comment: it says it can't find the file @Tom

Comment: Well, then you know that there is something wrong with the path. Check that it is really `"latest.txt"` and not `" latest.txt"` or `"latest.txt "` (mind the whitespaces).

Comment: Are you sure that file already exists before the Java program runs? Or are you expecting the Java code to automatically create the file if it doesn't exist (because that won't happen)? You'll have to use File#createNewFile().

Comment: no whitespace in the file name, really can'y see any issues with the path - perhaps 'Documents/My Documents' is causing the error? Also The file is already created

Comment: You've tried to open that directory in the shell? What does command `dir` print in that directory?

Comment: 09/01/2015  19:06                61 latest.txt.txtv @Tom

Comment: Right there, the file's not called `latest.txt`, it's `latest.txt.txtv`. remove the `.txtv` extension and you should be fine.

Comment: That worked, obviously. It's so frustrating when something is SO obvious but it's the last thing you actually check. Thanks everyone

Comment: You should set up explorer to show the file extensions. [This is how you do that](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/10570-file-extensions-hide-show.html).

Answer (score 3):

Believe the JVM when it tells you such things.  There's no sense insisting you're correct; you can't win that argument.  You need to figure out what you've done wrong.

My suggestion?  Try this:

```
    File f = new File("C:\\Users\\Joe\\Documents\\workspace\\ArtificialLifeFX\\res\\latest.txt");
```

On my Windows 7 machine it would be:

```
    File f = new File("C:\\Users\\Joe\\My Documents\\workspace\\ArtificialLifeFX\\res\\latest.txt");
```

Check your path to make sure it's absolutely spot on.

Comment: still no luck using those paths. While debugging the code and opening the path stored in the variable 'f' in windows explorer loads the .txt file correctly, so I'm not sure why Eclipse isn't finding it...

Comment: Using `/` instead of `\\\` is no problem.

Comment: Did you try duffymo's path with the last / between res and latest replaced with a \\?

Comment: yup, same error java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Joe\My Documents\workspace\ArtificialLifeFX\res\latest.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: Type 'windows + r' and then paste 'notepad C:\Users\Joe\My Documents\workspace\ArtificialLifeFX\res\latest.txt' and press enter. Does that open the file? Are you sure that file exists before the Java program runs? Or are you expecting the Java code to automatically create the file if it doesn't exist?

Comment: @nhylated You're too late :P. I asked that already and he said that he also gets an error, because the file could not be found (see the comments under the question). Therefore the file is really missing.

Comment: see comment in original post @nhylated

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the file exists but eclipse is not seeing it. Try to refresh the project in project explorer and make sure that this file appears under project explorer. Since the file you are referencing is under workspace folder than it should appear in the project explorer.